# Upload com erro CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boa noite. Gostaria de ajuda, se possível.

controller/documentos.php

```
public function clienteAdicionar(){

    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aDocumento')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para adicionar documentos.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->data['listaCliente'] = $this->documentos_model->getBase('cliente', 'razaosocial', 'ASC');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';


    if ($this->form_validation->run('documentos') == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {


        $field_name = "campo_arquivo";
        $this->documentos_model->do_upload($field_name);

    }
    $this->data['view'] = 'documentos/cadastros/adicionarCliente';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);

}
```

E também tenho o seguinte função dentro do model:

documentos_model.php

```
function do_upload()
{

    $date = date('d-m-Y');

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/arquivos/'.$date;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|pdf|PDF|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG';
    $config['max_size']     = 0;
    $config['max_width']  = '3000';
    $config['max_height']  = '2000';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = true;


    if (!is_dir('./assets/arquivos/'.$date)) {

        mkdir('./assets/arquivos/' . $date, 0777, TRUE);

    }

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Erro ao fazer upload do arquivo, verifique se a extensão do arquivo é permitida.');
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/documentos/clienteAdicionar/');
    }
    else
    {
        //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        return $this->upload->data();
    }
}
```

Adicionar cliente:
adicionarCliente.php

```
            <form class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" id="formArquivo">
            <?php 
                if($this->uri->segment(4)=="editar"){
                    echo form_hidden('idDocumento',$result->idDocumento);
                }
            ?>

            <fieldset>
                    <legend><i class="icon-plus icon-title"></i> Novo Documento</legend>
                    <div class="line">
                        <p>
                          <label class="control-label">Cliente</label>
                          <select class="input-xxlarge" name="tipo" id="tipo" style="width: 715px !important;" autofocus>
                            <option value="">Selecione o Cliente</option>
                            <? foreach($this->data['listaCliente'] as $listaCliente){ ?>
                            <option value="<? echo $listaCliente->idCliente; ?>" <? if(isset($result->idAdministrador)){ if($listaCliente->idCliente==$result->idAdministrador){ echo "selected"; } } ?>><? echo $listaCliente->razaosocial; ?></option>
                            <? } ?>
                          </select>
                          <br>
                      </p>
                        <p>&nbsp; </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="line">
                        <label class="control-label">Nome do Arquivo</label>
                        <input id="dp1" class="input-small" style="width: 701px !important;" name="nomearquivo" value="" type="text" placeholder="Nome do Arquivo" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="line">
                        <label class="control-label">Arquivo </label>
                        <input id="campo_arquivo" type="file" class="input-small" name="campo_arquivo" /> (txt|pdf|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)
                    </div>


                <div class="button-form line">                                          
                    <div class="span6 offset3" style="text-align: center">
                    <? if($this->uri->segment(2)=="editar"){ ?>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Alterar</button>
                    <? } else { ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnContinuar"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Adicionar</button>
                    <? } ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/documentos" class="btn"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Voltar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

O erro que dá, é que não faz UPLOAD, não vem os dados do formulário, por mais que eu altere o campo para default (userfile), mas também não funciona.
Alguém pode me auxiliar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigos,
Consegui apontar a solução. Se servir para alguém, ai está: No controller mesmo fiz esta função.

```
public function clienteAdicionar(){

    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aDocumento')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para adicionar documentos.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->data['listaCliente'] = $this->documentos_model->getBase('cliente', 'razaosocial', 'ASC');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';


    if ($this->form_validation->run('documentos') == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {

        #diretorio de upload
        $diretorio = 'assets/documentos/clientes/'.date("Y-m-d");

        if(!is_dir($diretorio)){
            mkdir($diretorio, 0777, TRUE);
            chmod($diretorio, 0777);
        }

        #configuracoes base
        $config['upload_path'] = $diretorio;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_size'] = '8192'; // 8Mbs

        #inicia a biblioteca
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        #faz upload
        $this->upload->do_upload(); 
        $arquivo = $this->upload->data();

        #dados do banco de dados
        $file = $arquivo['file_name'];
        $path = $arquivo['full_path'];
        $url = $diretorio.'/'.$file;
        $tamanho = $arquivo['file_size'];
        $tipo = $arquivo['file_ext'];

        $data = date("Y-m-d");
        $data = array(
            'nomearquivo' => $this->input->post('nomearquivo'),
            'idAdministrador' => $this->input->post('idAdministrador'),
            'modulo' => 'cliente',
            'arquivo' => $file,
            'diretorio' => $path,
            'url' => $url,
            'data' => $data,
            'tamanho' => $tamanho,
            'extensao' => $tipo
        );

        if ($this->documentos_model->add('documento', $data) == TRUE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Arquivo adicionado com sucesso!');
           redirect(base_url() . 'documentos/cadastros/adicionarCliente');
        } else {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>Ocorreu um erro.</p></div>';
        }


    }
    $this->data['view'] = 'documentos/cadastros/adicionarCliente';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);

}
```